# Expand $ f(z)=\frac {e^{2z}}{(z-1)^3}$ about $z=1$ as a Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Expand $$f(z)=\frac {e^{2z}}{(z-1)^3}$$ about $z=1$ as a Laurent;s series. Also indcate the region of convergence.

My attempt :

Let the given complex function be analytic in an annulus $r<|z-1|<R$ Then $f(z)$ can be expanded into a laurent's series about $z=1$

Let $z-1=u$ then $z=u+1$ Putting in $f(z)$ and expanding, i get

$$f(z)=\frac {1}{u^3}[1+2(u+1)+2(u+1)^2+...]$$

Does it look good ?

Comment: I may be wrong here, I think one approach might be to write $(z-1)^{3}f(z)=e^{2z}$ in taylor series and then justify if you can bring $(z-1)^{3}$ over...

Comment: It looks like a very fine idea...but the part inside your square brackets is *not* the expansion of $\;e^{2z}=e^{2(u+1)}\;$ ...

Comment: Start with
$$ e^{2z}=e^2e^{2(z-1)}=e^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2(z-1))^k}{k!}.$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better approach is to factor out an $e^{2}$ before using the series expansion for $e^{2z}$

So you get: $$f(u)=\frac{e^{2u+2}}{u^{3}}=\frac{e^{2}e^{2u}}{u^{3}}=\frac{e^{2}}{u^{3}}[1+2u+2u^{2}+\frac{4}{3}u^{3}+...]$$

This way you don't have to worry about all the $u+1$ terms.

Comment: nice !! Thanks.